# How to changes axes size within a fix figure in python?

Tags: python, axes

This code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(facecolor=(1, 0, 0, .1))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
plt.show()
```

Outputs a pink frame for the figure, with a white frame within it for the axes-object. Now, is it possible to change the size of the axes-object within the figure, without changing the figure size?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if this is what you want. You could change the fixed size values given inside the function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import Divider, Size
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.mpl_axes import Axes


def demo_fixed_size_axes():
    fig = plt.figure(facecolor=(1, 0, 0, .1))


    # The first items are for padding and the second items are for the axes.
    # sizes are in inch.
    h = [Size.Fixed(1.0), Size.Fixed(4.5)]
    v = [Size.Fixed(0.7), Size.Fixed(5.)]

    divider = Divider(fig, (0.0, 0.0, 1., 1.), h, v, aspect=False)
    # the width and height of the rectangle is ignored.
    ax = Axes(fig, divider.get_position())
    ax.set_axes_locator(divider.new_locator(nx=1, ny=1))

    fig.add_axes(ax)

    # ax.plot([1, 2, 3])
    plt.show()

demo_fixed_size_axes()
```